# How to set / get div input tag value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a piece of HTML code, where am trying to extract value of that text box which is defined using jQuery/ javascript

HTML code:

```
<div id="Account" class="leaf">
    <label class="control input text" title="">
        <span class="wrap">Select Account Number</span>
        <input class="" type="text" value="[Null]">
        <span class="warning"></span>
    </label>
</div>
```

SCRIPT code:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
alert(jQuery('#Account label.control input').val());
jQuery('#Account label.control input text').val("abc1001");
console.log("11");

}, false);
```

Here, when the page is loaded then it is displaying an alert box with "undefined" after that it displays at console 11 but it is not setting value 'abc1001' to the textbox which am focusing.

Need your valuable suggestions to set value.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3):

You have wrong selector which does not target textbox. Try this:

```
jQuery('#Account label.control input').val("abc1001");
```

as you have only one textbox in `#Account`,you can also use:

```
jQuery('#Account input').val("abc1001");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    alert($('#Account label.control input').val());
    $('#Account label.control input').val("abc1001");
    console.log("11");
    }, false);
```

I changed jQuery to $ and used jquery-1.11.0.min.js library it works..try this

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(function() {
    alert(jQuery('#Account label.control input').val());
    jQuery('#Account label.control input[type=text]').val("abc1001");
    console.log("11");    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve your issue easily , we can add some class to the input text box and then set value to that element.

HTML CODE

```
<div id="Account" class="leaf">
    <label class="control input text" title="">
      <span class="wrap">Select Account Number</span>
      <input class="some_class" type="text" value="[Null]">
      <span class="warning"></span>
    </label>
</div>
```

SCRIPT CODE

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() 
{
  alert(jQuery('.some_class').val());
  jQuery('.some_class').val("abc1001");
  console.log("11");
}, false);
```

and if you don't want to add class then simply remove 'text' thing from selector

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() 
{
  alert(jQuery('#Account label.control input').val());
  jQuery('#Account label.control input').val("abc1001");
  console.log("11");
}, false);
```

Hope it helps..!!